# Apex trigger for validation

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I have a custom object "Demo" having 2 fields "**Name(Type=text)**" & "**Marks(Type=percent)**". So generally marks in percentage cannot exceed 100.

So I want to create a trigger in Apex which will be triggered whenever I insert a new record. That trigger should check the value in percent field should be less than or equal to 100 and through the respective error.

Note:I can simply use validation rule to achieve this. But I would want to do this using Apex for my practice purpose. I have written below code untill now.

```
trigger ValidateMarks on ForTriggerPractice__c (before insert) {

}
```

Could anyone help me out.

Comment: Can post your code whatever you have practiced so far

Comment: This is not a freelance site to post requirement and get the appropriate code; but rather a developer forum. People are happy to help you, if you show some efforts, so kindly edit your post and share what you have tried so far. Also I would encourage to visit this trailhead module- [Get Started with Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_intro)

Comment: You should check out the **Trailhead** platform.

Comment: @RahulSharma Sorry Rahul. I stuck in the middle so I posted it. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @sujit - Not sure that counts as an attempt. Thats like saying help me writing this paragraph, I have this so far "Chapter 1.........The end" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point to be remembered

1) Trigger need to be bulkified
2) Move code to handler.
3) Check if iteration needed or not and complete trailhed fist

**Trigger**

```
trigger ValidateMarks on ForTriggerPractice__c (before insert,before update) {
        ValidateMarksHandler.validatePercentage(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);
    }
```

**Class**

```
public  class ValidateMarksHandler{

    public static validatePercentage(Map<Id,ForTriggerPractice__c> newMap, Map<Id,ForTriggerPractice__c> oldMap){
        // Insert case 
        if(oldMap == NULL || oldMap.size() == 0){
            for(ForTriggerPractice__c temp : newMap.values()){
                if(temp.Marks__c <> NULL && temp.Marks__c < 0 && temp.Marks__c >100){
                    temp.addError(' Not in valid Marks range [valid range is 0 to 100] ');
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            for(ForTriggerPractice__c temp : newMap.values()){
                ForTriggerPractice__c oldInstance = oldMap.get(temp.Id);
                if(oldInstance.Marks__c <> temp.Marks__c && temp.Marks__c <> NULL && temp.Marks__c < 0 && temp.Marks__c >100){
                    temp.addError(' Not in valid Marks range [valid range is 0 to 100] ');
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue with the code?

Comment: Checking whether it matches the old value seems like over-engineering, you'd have fewer comparisons if you just check whether it is within the range whenever the trigger fires.

Comment: Yes, agreed but it's for the learning purpose only, not an actual live requirement.

Comment: Thanks @AvijitChakraborty I got what I need from your code